# "Нечто(,) вроде"

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то меня заклинило. В обороте "нечто(,) вроде" нужна запятая или нет?
Заранее спасибо за помощь, а то что-то сообразить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

нет, не нужна, если там нет пояснения (нужно давать всё предложение): http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_110